# SqlLite 3 - "Unable to open database"

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net, asp.net-web-api

I have created a SqlLite 3 db file and placed in my project's App_Data folder (ASP.Net Web API). I can't seem to connect to it. The exception message is vague and I cannot determine what is wrong. Permissions? File Not Found? No idea.

I have created the following connectionString entry in my web.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="LiteConnection" connectionString="Data Source=~\App_Data\repository.s3db;Version=3;" />
```

The exception is throw when I attempt to Open() a connection. I'm beginning to suspect that maybe IISExpress (VS2012) cannot write to this dir or something??

```
  private string _dbLitePath = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LiteConnection"].ConnectionString;

...
      public IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_connection == null)
                _connection = new SQLiteConnection(_dbLitePath);

            if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _connection.ConnectionString = _dbLitePath;
                _connection.Open(); // kaaaaasplat!
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {

        }
        return _connection;
    }
```

Comment: Whats the exception you get?

Comment: So if you step into this code during Debugging, what is the value of _dbLitePath  ?  If it is not the full system path, e.g. "C:\whatever", then that is your problem.

Comment: The exception was just as I stated. "unable to open database file" - Not helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change you connection string to:

```
 connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\repository.s3db
```

> DataDirectory is a substitution string that indicates the path to the
>   database. It eliminates the need to hard-code the full path which
>   leads to several problems as the full path to the database could be
>   serialized in different places. DataDirectory also makes it easy to
>   share a project and also to deploy an application.

Reference to [Where is DataDirectory](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/)

Comment: I'm trying it. Doesn't it require that I 'do' the substitution in code? i.e. provide the datadirectory

Comment: You can change in code the location (before trying any data access code) with  `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", " ....." ));`  but the string |DataDirectory| should be already there

Comment: You cannot point your DB connection string to a Relative URL.  Those only make sense to the Web framework, not the ODBC driver.  Use the Data Directory as Steve Suggests.  By default it is the App_Data folder under the project.

Comment: Hours and hours on this because I was using CTX.Server.MapPath(@"App_Data\TranslatorDB.sl3"); which works in .NET Forms but not MVC !!! GEEZ!